# Coredata fetching inside a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am suppose to fetch a record from the coredata based on id.Since i am fetching inside a for loop for each iteration the execution time is very large. Can some one tell me how i can do this efficiently.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [tempCodeDescArray count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *codeDescDict = [tempCodeDescArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemId=%@",[codeDescDict valueForKey:@"itemId"]];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        NSError *error=nil;
         NSArray *result=[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }
```

Comment: u can do it in another way-> fetch all data in one FetchRequest then make a loop on result this make it faster. access data  one time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an array with all ids that you want to fetch:

```
NSArray *idsToFetch = [tempCodeDescArray valueForKey:@"itemId"];
```

and fetch all objects with a single fetch request, using the predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemId IN %@", idsToFetch];
```

(If you need this for importing data, I can also recommend to read
[Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) in the "Core Data Programming Guide".)

Comment: Great solution just wanted to post the same answer here, so, for sure this is the best one.